# Как можно приблизительно оценить размер индекса до его создания?

Tags: sql, oracle, index

Планируется добавить индекс в таблицу, но хотелось бы сначала оценить размер индекса, какой будет после его создания (не нужен точный размер,  только ориентировочный).

Допустим, есть доступ ко всем метаданным о таблице (количество строк, столбцов, типы данных и т.д.), и возможно выполнить любой SQL запрос, чтобы получить дополнительные данные о текущем состоянии таблицы. Также доподлинно известно, каким будет определение индекса.

Как можно приблизительно оценить размер этого индекса до его создания?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I estimate the size of an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/827123) от участника [@Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44757/jared)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/827123

Answer (score 4):

Можно оценить размер индекса, выполнив [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/EXPLAIN-PLAN.html#GUID-FD540872-4ED3-4936-96A2-362539931BA0) для запроса на создание индекса:

```
create table t (val) as
    select rownum  
    from dual connect by level <= 1e6;    

explain plan for
    create index ti on t (val);

select * 
from table (dbms_xplan.display (null, null, 'basic +note'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2855645439
 
---------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name |
---------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE INDEX STATEMENT |      |
|   1 |  INDEX BUILD NON UNIQUE| TI   |
|   2 |   SORT CREATE INDEX    |      |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | T    |
---------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - estimated index size: 24M bytes
```

Обратите внимание на опцию `+NOTE` в функции [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-FDE553FD-2099-47B6-A1F8-83BFFDCF5662). Она добавила раздел *Note* внизу, в котором и есть приблизительная оценка размера индекса. В данном случае - 24МБ.

Само собой разумеется, индекс при этом не будет создан:

```
select * from user_indexes where table_name='T';

no rows selected
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939505) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>